# Having trobule getting a cursor to appear when I hover over a button

Tags: css, hover, cursor

I created this HTML

```
<span class="buttonContainer"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" method="put" class="btn"></span>
```

and wanted a cursor (pointer) to appear when I roll over it.  So I added this CSS

```
.buttonContainer {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

but no pointer appears when I hover above the button.  I created this JS fiddle to illustrate the problem — https://jsfiddle.net/pj528mqo/2/ .

Any ideas how to get a cursor to appear when I hover above the button in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button inside the container is the same size and doesn't show a cursor on hover. You could add this rule to make all elements inside the container to show a cursor on hover:

```
.buttonContainer *:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/49noydup/.

Answer (score 0):

Put   cursor: pointer; on .btn class

```
.btn{  cursor: pointer;}
```